# Socket broadcasting a packet

Tags: sockets, networking

So I know how to broadcast a packet on the LAN (send it to x.x.x.255) IP. I am confused on how to receive the packet on the receiving host. Like i don't know what kind of socket connection I need to use. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Search for "socket broadcast + <language>" with your programming language. You'll most likely find lots of examples including the "server" (the program that broadcasts the packets) and the "client" (the program that receives them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use UDP sockets. At receiving side just keep on listening like any normal UDP socket. No special setup is needed.

Comment: in the client side, what ip and port i should use? i guess i am confused with the broadcasting process

Comment: So port will be the same on which you are broadcasting. At client side no IP is needed as UDP is connection less protocol.